# Google DFP JW Player Integration

Tags: jwplayer, google-dfp, vast, double-click-advertising

I am trying to create a VAST video ad tag from google DFP :-

```
https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?iu=/426618404/dfp_adtest&description_url=https%3A%2F%2Freacho.in%2Freturn-of-vignaharta-reacho.html&env=vp&impl=s&correlator=&tfcd=0&npa=0&gdfp_req=1&output=vast&sz=640x480&unviewed_position_start=1
```

But this Tag response is coming empty. When i try to test it in Google Ad inspector , it gives me an error :- "(3:19:30 PM) Ad error: AdError 1009: The VAST response document is empty."

That is why i am unable to integrate this Ad tag with JW Player. I want to know what are things i am doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you misconfigured your DFP setup so your question has little to do with jwplayer

Comment: Does your player support VAST3.0?